# Overwrite template's stylesheet with the one from custom component in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

In my custom Joomla 3 extension I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 for the front-end. I noticed that the default Joomla template protostar overwrites default Bootstrap classes which is not what I would like. Is there a way to load my stylesheet after the template's stylesheets so they overwrite any common rules may exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

This will add the `css` at your component calling time inside the component `HTML` section . Keep in mind it will not add the `css` at head section but for sure it will appear after the template `css`

```
    $stylelink = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/css.css" />';
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->addCustomTag($stylelink);
```

Hope it works..